# Dynamically created button

Tags: asp.net

When I click a button I need to create some Textboxes dynamically. The values of the textboxes must be entered in the database by clicking a button which should be enerated dynamically below these textboxes. How do I acheive this?? I need to have a Click event for this newly generated button.

Answer (score 1):

Use ASP.NET MVC, if you want dynamic creation of elements on your page, MVC Framework is much better suited for this than Webforms are. Save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply handle the input of the new data in Page_Load on postback and have your newly created button just postback the form.  You'll need to look through the form parameters for the new textboxes, obviously, and have a way to differentiate them from the previously existing ones.

If you must handle them with a button click event handler, you could try adding a hidden ("display: none;", not "visible=false") button to your page and associating a server-side click handler with it.  Have the client-side click handler cause a click-event on the hidden button when it is clicked.  This should invoke the server-side click handler for the hidden button.  Again, you'll need to find the new textboxes in the request's form parameters since they won't exist as server-side controls.

Comment: im not that experienced in ASP.NET. Can u help me with some code??